# Xcode 5 does not recognize custom UIViewController subclass in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a storyboard app in Xcode 5 with many custom view controllers and segues and everything works well, except in one case.  In this case, I have a "View Controller Scene" where I am trying to use a custom UIViewController subclass.  But even though I specify the subclass, the entry in the sidebar is still called "View Controller Scene" and the View Controller entry for that scene is shown as just the generic "View Controller" (where in every other case, the scene label is changes to reflect the subclass, as is the View Controller entry).

So, Xcode does not appear to believe that I have specified a custom class for the View Controller for this scene.  If it were only interface builder that was confused, that would be fine, but when I run the code, when I prepareForSegue: for the appropriate segue, the destinationViewController is a UIViewController, while I need it to be the custom subclass.

I know that my custom class must be a subclass of UIViewController, and it is (although several steps removed -- that is, it is a subclass of a subclass of a subclass of UIViewController).

The problem is not the Xcode 5 bug of not recognizing custom classes (the class name does show up in autocomplete for the Custom Class field) and Xcode has been restarted many times since this custom class was created.

So, what am I missing?  What could cause Xcode 5 not to recognize a custom class for a UIViewController?

Comment: I've seen this happen sometimes.  It's usually cleared up by some combination of clean, rebuild, and reboot Xcode.  Basically Xcode isn't finding your custom class declaration (the .h file)

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, try deleting the vc from your storyboard and recreating.

Comment: Another longshot, make sure the custom class is included in the build target.  I've had it get unchecked and drop off the radar that way.

Comment: To echo what David says, I've seen this many many many times. First try compiling, if that doesn't work then exit Xcode, if that doesn't work then clean,  exit, clean, compile.

Comment: what exact name did you use to create that VC? if I start VC name with word Final in Xcode5.1 it just does not show up in custom class list. So try diff names.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers (I did not realize anyone had answered until just now -- thought I would get mail).  The bottom line is that it does just seem to be some combination of restarting Xcode + clean + who knows what.  After moving on to other things, this magically cleared up.  I really appreciate everyone's thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happens all the time, easiest way to solve it: quit Xcode and run it again. The view controller should now be visible.

Comment: Gabriel: thanks for answering.  This was not, on its own, enough (I mentioned in the original post that restarting Xcode did not solve it), but restarting was probably part of the answer, because it did eventually start working.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I guess I will mark this answer as Accepted because it is certainly part of the issue and I want the question to be marked as resolved.  Tell me if this is not the right approach!

Comment: Just quitting that particular project wasn't enough in my case. You literally had to exit out of all your projects on Xcode. and restart xcode ... sigh

Comment: The issue still exists in xcode 6. Ffs Apple, how about actually fixing stuff in updates instead of just making things look prettier.

Answer (score 0):

Its a thing that just happens sometimes, I usually ignore it, copy the name in and hit enter, but if its bothering you, you can try to clean and build your project, should start showing up then clean: `cmd + shift + k` build: `cmd + b`

good luck!

Comment: Some combination of events did get this working eventually (wish I could say just what, but I had moved on to other problems when it started working).  However, a simple clean + rebuild was not enough (at least on its own) even after entering the subclass name, because I would still get unrecognized selector errors.  Finally, however, something worked, because the errors did eventually go away.  Thanks for your suggestions.